# Arrays in structures and access methods

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Looks like something basic. 
But I'm unable to see why

```
(*ptr).my_data_ptr->my_data[0].b
```

works, whereas

```
*((*ptr).my_data_ptr).my_data[0].b
```

doesn't.

I'm giving the relation between the various datatypes below:

```
typedef struct { int a; int b;} MY_DATA;
typedef struct { MY_DATA my_data[2];} MY_DATA_ARR;
typedef struct { MY_DATA_ARR *my_data_ptr;} MY_PARAM;
typedef MY_PARAM * MY_PARAM_PTR;
```

Comment: Replace `(*ptr).my_data_ptr` with a variable name and you'll see why the two expressions are not equivalent. `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`; the parenthesis are required because [`.` has higher precedence than `*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Why use either one in the first place?  `ptr->my_data_ptr->my_data[0].b`. Simple, tells the story.

Comment: @n.m, yes you're correct. But reason for using this method is not me :-), but another framework which generates this expression. Thanks for bringing this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`, **not** `*a.b`. Refer to [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the precedence of member access `.` is higher than dereference `*`.

Change to this - it will work:

```
(*((*ptr).my_data_ptr)).my_data[0].b
```

Comment: Or even `(*(*ptr).my_data_ptr).my_data[0].b`, as field selectors have higher precedence than the dereference `*` operator.  Always thinkg that the left monadic operators have less precedence than right ones.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence.  In this: `*((*ptr).my_data_ptr).my_data[0].b`

The `.` before `my_data` is evaluated before the leading `*`.  Neither "dereference" nor "multiplication" using `*` will be evaluated before a `.`.

[c](/questions/tagged/c) tries very hard to guess what you want and will find a way to use what you provide.  If it can make *something* compile it will, even if it is not what you really wanted, which is why it does not flag even a warning.

Comment: Computers never do what you want, as they always do what you say (and in case of dispute, the second part prevaleces)

Comment: "Implementation defined feature" is a four-letter word, but all too true.